# Specify element to go beyond page margin in android scrollview/listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview

I have a linear layout in which I have 3 views.

[image]

```
View1-Weight=1
View2-Weight=10
View3-Weight=1
```

Total weight is 12.

Now all elements have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Which means that the screen is divided in proportion of their heights.

What I want to do is that I want to nest 3 ImageViews in View2 so that each image view fully occupies the available screen area to View2. And on scrolling, I must see the second image view and third image views respectively. Each must be continuous and sizes(of ImageViews) must become equal. If all were to be on a single page, I would have done it by setting their weights.But now since they are on different pages, I dont have an idea how to do it. I dont want to take absolute sizes as it may look ugly on different devices.

How is it possible and what should be used in View2-a ListView or a Scrollview? Is it possible via the xml file(my preferred solution).

Comment: Always use layout_width = "0dip" whenever you are using layout_weight in linear layout

Comment: I am using layout_height="0dp" as I want to divide screen in height not in width @Dr.aNdRO

Comment: ok I am not getting what your are trying to say on the line "each image view fully occupies the available screen area to View2". Can you please specify more clearly? I have tried many customization to layouts, but I am not getting you.

Comment: It would be better if you draw an image on paint what exactly you want and add it here in the question.

Comment: In simple words, in view2(=listview/scrollview/linearlayout whatever...), on one page, only Imageview must be shown.Rest Imageviews must be forced on the second/third pages and must appear on scroll @Dr.aNdRO

Comment: you can try Fixed size view pager which have will lie in the view 2 covering entire area. And add all three image view in page array?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO see image. Not sure if a view pager would make images appear continuous.

Comment: It will tell me is if you want your image view to slide horizontally?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Vertically.I mean scrolling must be vertical.And thats obvious as I already said that layout_width="match_parent".

Answer (score 0):

Ok So here is the basic idea :
You cannot use a ScrollView or a ListView or a GridView here perfectly as you have not specified the width and height in a fixed manner by applying dp and dip. So the only thing will work here is a ViewPager([A modified version](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager)) It will scroll vertically. So heres how to do this.

You have 3 Views in the layout.

```
<View
  android:id="v1"
  android:weight="1.0"
....
/>

<View
  android:id="v1"
  android:weight="10.0"
....
>
<ViewPager
 //so you must specify the width and height here as fill parent
   android:width="fill_parent"
   android:height="Fill_parent"
/>

</View>
<View
  android:id="v1"
  android:weight="1.0"
....
/>
```

Just use this view pager and you must specify your fragment imageview by supplying it the property of **fitXY**, it will force fix your one ImageView to be visible in the entire view 2 at a time then you can scrol vertically to access other two.